# Разобраться в примере вывода PID всех процессов

Tags: c++

[По этой ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process) есть пример вывода всех процессов. Не могу понять, для чего нужен один момент:

```
DWORD cbNeeded; 
DWORD cProcesses;
...
cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
```

Для чего здесь нужно делить cbNeeded на sizeof(DWORD)?

Да и довольно часто встречается деление переменной на sizeof(...). Где можно почитать, для чего это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В описании ф-ции [EnumProcesses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) сказано, что cbNeeded - это длина заполненной части массива в байтах.

Чтобы перевести ее в количество элементов мы делим на длину элемента массива в байтах, который вычисляется с помощью sizeof.